# Growl 1.3+: Location of (rollup) Log for use with GeekTool

Tags: logs, growl, geektool

Where can I find Growl's log(s)? Would like to use with GeekTool to display it on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Growl uses a CoreData database located in ~/Library/Application Support/Growl/

The database is a file called notifications.history

Edit: there does not as yet appear to be any way to communicate with the Growl Control Suite say via AppleScript, to read the database.  The functions there are limited. See [the Growl AppleScript documentation here](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support#growlcontrol)

You would have to communicate with the database directly, a database model is included within each build of Growl.

Comment: Got it. So, there's no easy/possible way of tailing some sort of log file then? Maybe there's a workaround? Does it append its output from the Rollup into some existing log file in the filesystem, that you can `ack`? A newbie suspect would be into the system.log, but that might be a dumb thought. (Just thinking.)

Comment: @hced - not currently AFAIK, although the Rollup notification center is very new to Growl having only been introduced in 1.3 and I would expect that it will receive further enhancements in the near future.  I did notice that the code does do a lot of logging via NSLog so there may be "some" information in the console however there may not be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

They're located at `~/Library/Application Support/Growl/notifications.history`.